How to change fill to image in Python
I want to change the background from regular collor fill to image.
This is my code:
# ==== show board block when it is empty
def show_number0(self, row, column, a, b, c, d):
    self.square[row, column] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(a, b, c, d, fill="#232020", tags="rect", outline="")

I tried many different things but none of them worked

What is self.canvas? Where is it defined/by what library? Have you reviewed the documentation of this library to verify it even supports image fills to begin with?

this is probably tkinter - the OP needs to call itemconfig method - bt as a newcomer, they failed to paste a minimal reproducible example.

You can use the canvas.itemconfig method:
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(win)
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill="red")
canvas.pack()
win.update()
# at this point, a red square is seen, if one is using the interactive mode.
canvas.itemconfig(rect, fill="blue")
win.update()


"I want to change the background from regular collor fill to image" - OP wants to change a filled rectangle to image instead.
